# Extracting Haralick features from GLCM. Why do I get multiple values for each feature?

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-extraction, scikit-image, glcm

I have seen [this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fjp.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Fanswers%2Fuploaded_files%2F25743%2FFinalAlgorithm.pdf) paper yesterday. In this paper the features are taken as **contrast**, **local homogeneity** and **energy**, which all are a single values (as per my knowledge) but according to skimage fuction `greycomatrix`, the parameters passed to these that are `distances` and `angles` (which can be more than one).

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
from skimage import io, color, img_as_ubyte

img = cv2.imread('Grape___Black_rot28.JPG')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    

distances = [1, 2, 3]
angles = [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4]
glcm = greycomatrix(gray_image, 
                    distances=distances, 
                    angles=angles,
                    symmetric=True,
                    normed=True)

properties = ['contrast', 'energy', 'homogeneity', 'correlation', 'dissimilarity']
contrast = greycoprops(glcm, properties[0])
energy = greycoprops(glcm, properties[1])
homogeneity = greycoprops(glcm, properties[2])
correlation = greycoprops(glcm, properties[3])
dissimilarity = greycoprops(glcm, properties[4])
```

What confuses me is if I generate a glcm of contrast property it will be of 3x4 size but according to the paper it is a single value and even if I consider all 3x4 values of all the properties as a feature, I bet it will have a over-fitting problem for svm model.

Comment: Could you show us the rest of the code?

Comment: @Tonechas check the code on the above link

Comment: My project is for detecting disease in leaves by image processing. Currently I am in feature extraction phase

Answer (score 1):

From [`graycoproprops`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.greycoprops) documentation:

> **Returns:     results : 2-D ndarray**
>
> 2-dimensional array. results[d, a] is the property ‘prop’ for the d’th
>                       distance and the a’th angle.

Your code yields a feature value for each distance-angle combination:

```
In [5]: len(distances)
Out[5]: 3

In [6]: len(angles)
Out[6]: 4

In [7]: contrast.shape
Out[7]: (3, 4)
```

A common practice to achieve rotation invariance consists in averaging feature values along the `angles` axis. By doing so, you will get as many feature values as you have distances:

```
In [11]: contrast = greycoprops(glcm, properties[0]).mean(axis=1)

In [12]: contrast.shape
Out[12]: (3,)
```

Comment: so, doing averaging won't cost me a data loss

Comment: Averaging features along the `angles` axis makes your feature vector more compact (reduced dimensionality) and more robust (rotation invariant).